# Trigger on Slide Change in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a banner slider this one [Banner Slider](http://manos.malihu.gr/slidebox-jquery-banner-rotator) Where i want to trigger some event onSlide Change, by default its not available with this plugin.

```
(".slidebox").mSlidebox(function()
{
   //My action trigger here
});
```

How can i achieve that??

Comment: I see you commented on the post (http://manos.malihu.gr/slidebox-jquery-banner-rotator#comment-7662), and the author seems to be good at responding, but in the mean time I would suggest looking for another plugin _or_ trying to rig something else up yourself as per @blasteralfred's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may define your function here

```
slideboxNext.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    SlideboxAction("next","stop");
        YOUR FUNCTION HERE
});
slideboxPrevious.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    SlideboxAction("previous","stop");
        YOUR FUNCTION HERE
});
```

and in autoplay mode;

```
slideboxSlide.each(function(index){
    if(options.numberedThumbnails){
        slideboxThumbs.append("<a href='#' class='slideboxThumb' rel='"+(index+1)+"'>"+(index+1)+"</a>");
    }else{
        slideboxThumbs.append("<a href='#' class='slideboxThumb' rel='"+(index+1)+"' />");
    }
    $(this).attr("rel",index+1).addClass("slideboxSlide slideboxSlide_"+(index+1)).children().addClass("slideboxCaption");
    slideboxTotalWidth=(index+1)*slideboxWidth;
    slideboxSlides.css("width",slideboxTotalWidth);
    slideboxEnd=index*slideboxWidth;
    YOUR FUNCTION HERE
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, but im looking for autoChange trigger event not onClick... :(

Answer (score 0):

as you can see on each slide the style attribute of element with class of `slideboxSlides` is changed, you can use `DOMAttrModified` event of this element:

```
(".slidebox").mSlidebox(function()
{

document.getElementsByClassName('slideboxSlides').addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(e){
  if (e.attrName === 'style') {
    // My action trigger here...
  }
}, false);

});
```